# Is there a language whose syntactic structure accepts a specifier of a PP?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, x-bar-theory, prepositions, constituents

We know a preposition (in X-bar theory) is the **head of a prepositional phrase** and it has a complement that is the sister of this very preposition. However I've never seen a language with a constituent in the **specifier** position of the PP.

[image]

Is there a reason for that? Is there a language that fills it with something?

Answer (score 3):

In his syntax textbook, Richard Larson (2010: 346-7) suggests that measure phrases in PPs, e.g. “three miles” in “three miles down the road”, occupy the specifier of PP. If that’s correct, English is a language that can have constituents in Spec,PP - though it doesn’t always.

Answer (score 1):

English has PP specifiers!

> The bird flew *right* over us.

> My friend lives *just* around the corner.

Most dictionaries seem to call these adverbs, but syntactically they serve a different function than words like *quickly* or *carefully*, but I'm not aware of a different name in the literature for words like this.